# Is there any way to force a git add ignoring line ending problems?

Tags: git, line-endings

I have a giant directory which I need to import into git, and I am suffering the hell of line ending management.

Initially I need to just put everything inside the repo, having no time to deal with line endings. To get that, I added a `.gitattributes` file with `* -text`, but that doesn't solve the problem because there are lots of subdirectories containing modules with their own `.gitattributes` files and `text=auto`.

Is there any way to get all the files inside the repo with no more struggle?

Comment: Do you mean `.gitattributes`?  That's where things like `* -text` go ... not in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Sorry, mistake. Edited.

Comment: I just tested, git has no problem commiting files having unix or dos line endings into the same repository. Could you elaborate your problem further? What message do you get from git?

Comment: The problem appears with git add, which rejects files not according the current eol configuration (in tis case, dictated by gitattributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) states:

> When deciding what attributes are assigned to a path, Git consults:
>
> - `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file (which has the highest precedence),
> - `.gitattributes` file in the same directory as the path in question, and its parent directories up to the toplevel of the work tree (the further the directory that contains `.gitattributes` is from the path in question, the lower its precedence).
> - Finally global and system-wide files are considered (they have the lowest precedence).
>
> If you wish to affect only a single repository (i.e., to assign attributes to files that are particular to one user’s workflow for that repository), then attributes should be placed in the `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file.

So try and set your `* -text` directive in `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes`, at least for your initial add and commit.